# Cartesian product of sets. What is the ordering

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{a, b, b, c, b\}, B = \{b\}, and C = \{0, 1\}.$. For each of the following, find the set and
then state its cardinality.

$(a)~ D = A \times B\\
(b)~ A \times B \times C\\
(c)~ D \times C$

This is what I have so far
$A= a,b,c \\
B=b \\
C=0,1 \\
(a)~ D = A \times B \\
(a, b), (b, b), (c, b)\\
\text{The cardinality is }3 \\
(b)~ A \times B \times C = (a, b, 0), (a, b, 1), (b, b, 0), (b, b, 1), (c, b, 0), (c, b, 1) \\
\text{The cardinality is }6.$

$(c)~ ?$

Can someone please explain to me what the difference between $A \times B \times C$ and $D \times C$ is?

Comment: $A \times B \times C$ and $(A \times B) \times C$ are almost identical as you see. The difference may be their definitions (or how to write their elements).

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly should it be (c) D × C = ((a, b), 0), ((b, b), 0), ((c, b), 0), ((a, b), 1)((b, b), 1), ((c, b), 1)
The cardinality is 6.

Comment: Since some books define $A \times B \times C$ as $(A \times B) \times C$, I am not sure what the question is asking. I guess yes, but maybe no.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You have the product of a set of pairs with a set of values.